# How to Query nested Foreign Key shared attributes wih Django

Tags: python, django

I have a structure of objects with 4 layers of nested Foreign key relationships. On each level, I have an owner attribute for that object. I need to query the entire tree for objects owned by someone, and return the object owned by them and their parents all the way to the top level, even if they are not owned by the person I am filtering by.

```
class User:
  """only need to worry about id on this class"""

class Level1:
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Level2:
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Level1, related_name='level2')

class Level3:
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Level2, related_name='level3')

class Level4:
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Level3, related_name='level4')
```

Being the owner of an object does not guarantee the ownership of the children, and visa-versa.

I am hoping to return the following structure with a single DB query, in order to improve performance of my application. This query is executed very often, and a major bottleneck at the moment.

The desired structure is:

```
[
 {id: 1,
  type: Level1,
  owner: owner_id
  children:[
     {id: 1,
      type: Level2,
      owner: owner_id,
      children:[
        {id: 1,
         type: Level3,
         owner: owner_id,
         children:[
            {id: 1,
             type: Level4,
             owner: owner_id},
             {id: 2,
              type: Level4,
              owner: owner_id},
            ]},
         ]},
     {id: 2,
      type: Level2,
      owner: different_owner_id,
      children:[
         {id: 2,
          type: Level3,
          owner: different_owner_id,
          children:[
            {id: 3,
             type: Level4,
             owner: owner_id},        
             ]},
         ]},
    ]
  },
]
```

I have tried using Q objects but I know i am not using them correctly

```
my_list = Level1.object.all().filter(Q(owner=query_id) |
                                     Q(level2__owner=query_id) |
                                     Q(level2__level3__owner=query_id) |
                                     Q(level2__level3__level4__owner=query_id))
```

However, this returns a list of Level1 Objects, for each individual child object matching the criteria. The above example should return only 1 Level1 Object, but currently returns 6 Level1Objects (one for each Object in the structure that matches). I have all the objects I require, but they are unorganized and I do not know the correct way to assemble them.

I guess there are two solutions that I can pursue.

1. Create a better query that returns the objects correctly (preferred)
2. Write a serializer that will match up children and parents correctly.

Comment: You can't fetch everything in one query. But using [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) will help you restrict the number of queries to a minimum.

Comment: Also, as you noted, your filter is wrong, since you should just filter for the owner of the `Level1` object. It's not clear in your question which children you want, since your example shows children with a different owner, but your queryset attempt actually filters for children with the same owner.

Comment: Finally, for serialisation, are you using DRF? In which case it's just a matter of [nesting serialisers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Comment: The children that I desire are all Objects that are owned by the desired owner, plus all of the parents of those Objects, regardless of owner.

Comment: I am using DRF.

Comment: then why is `{id: 2,
      type: Level2,
      owner: different_owner_id, ...` in your example? it's a child of object `Level1` with id 1, but has a different owner.

Comment: It is included because one of children, 1 level removed ({id: 3, type: Level4, owner: owner_id}), is owned by the desired owner.

Comment: I think the best route is to write your nested serialisers, with the querysets for each serialiser having the correct filter (and prefetch_related)

Comment: Thank you for your input! I appreciate it